# Chart Not Showing in Web Browser | Plotly | Python

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, plotly, data-visualization

I have just started learning `Plotly` and it shows graph and chart correctly in `Jupyter Notebook`. But when I run the same script `.py` in text editor or from cmd it open a window in browser but then it shows

> Unable to Connect
>   Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:5875.
>    and did not shows an chart or graph.

Anyone has idea how to do this? Basically I want to show data from `csv` in Web Browser.

Comment: If you use `%run` in front of your script name to run it from within the Jupyter notebook, does that show your plot?

Comment: Yes in Jupyter notebook, everything works fine and even when I run simple script with `.py` extension it runs without error but nothing shows in browser.

Answer (score 6):

The `write_html` exports the Plotly figure as an html file and opens it on the web browser.

```
figure.write_html( 'output_file_name.html', 
                   auto_open=True )
```

Further information [plotly.io.write_html](https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.io.write_html.html)